# The vue router fails after vite vue3 is built. A blank page is displayed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I was using wails of golang to build a desktop program, in which the front-end introduced the Vue Router. When npm run dev was used, the page could be normally opened and displayed. However, when npm run build was used to build packages, the page content was displayed blank, and no error occurred on the console. I don't know where the problem is at the moment

vite.config.js

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from 'path' 

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
})
```

main.ts

```
import {createApp} from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import {create, NBreadcrumb, NBreadcrumbItem, NButton, NCard, NCode, NConfigProvider, NFlex, NForm, NFormItem, NGi, NGradientText, NGrid, NInput, NLayout, NLayoutSider, NLog, NMessageProvider, NModal, NSelect, NSpin, NTree} from 'naive-ui'
import './style.css';

const naive = create({
    components: [
        NButton,
        NInput,
        NCard,
        NFlex,
        NGrid,
        NGi,
        NForm,
        NFormItem,
        NSelect,
        NMessageProvider,
        NLayout,
        NLayoutSider,
        NBreadcrumb,
        NBreadcrumbItem,
        NConfigProvider,
        NLog,
        NCode,
        NSpin,
        NTree,
        NModal,
        NGradientText
    ]
})

createApp(App).use(router).use(store).use(naive).mount('#app')
```

router.ts

```
import {createRouter, createWebHashHistory, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router'
import Layout from '../components/layout/index.vue'

const routes: any[] = [
    {
        path: '/', 
        component: Layout,
        name: 'layout',
        redirect: '/index',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'index',
                path: '/index',
                component: import('@/pages/index/index.vue')
            },
            {
                name: 'get_token',
                path: '/get_token',
                component: import('@/pages/interior/get_token.vue')
            },
            {
                name: 'iot_sync_package',
                path: '/iot_sync_package',
                component: import('@/pages/iot/sync_package.vue')
            },
            {
                name: 'permissions',
                path: '/permissions',
                component: import('@/pages/interior/permissions.vue')
            },
            {
                name: 'permissions',
                path: '/gen_code',
                component: import('@/pages/core/gen_code.vue')
            }
        ]
    }
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHashHistory(),
    routes
})

router.onError((handler) => {
    console.error(handler)
})

export default router
```

How do I display properly in wails

Comment: main.go sets the basic window size and references app.go. It is worth mentioning that I will start a websocket service in the startup function, and then reference my own service business logic business logic code in the app structure

Comment: I think the problem may not have appeared in wails. When I packaged the application using npm run build alone, it was indeed a blank page after launching with live-server. I think the problem may have appeared in the front-end code, but no problem was found after checking for a long time

Comment: after you build, do you deploy the built code anywhere, or are you using golang to serve from the build folder? also, with the blank page, no errors at all in the browser console? no content?

Comment: Yes, after the construction was completed, I used live-server to provide the web local port service in the dist directory built by npm, and then I received a blank page, and the browser console did not have any error output

Comment: If the content from the server is empty then your server is poorly written

Comment: In your router.ts file try changing `component: import('@/pages/index/index.vue')` to `component: () => import('@/pages/index/index.vue')` (add the arrow function to all)... I had exactly this issue with vue router on vite a few days ago.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it your way and it worked for me.